# Linq query record with condition where column is null

Tags: c#, linq

I have a reference table with values to refer with. My major key is the first column, but i will also check whether there are exceptions for that key. My Table:

```
StudentID   ExceptionlalRecord  Other Details
---------   ------------------  -------------
Student1    null                BlaBla
Student2    null                BlaBla
Student1    123                 BlaBla
```

The table doesnot have primary key(Database First), during designing of the model i made both StudentID & ExceptionlalRecord primary keys but nullable false in the property for the columns.

What i am trying to do is during normal request get students that dont have exceptional record & if provided return students with exceptional records, which will provide me different Other Details column data.

```
QueryStudentId=ProvidedByRequest;
QueryExceptionalRecord=ProvidedByRequest;

if(db.StudentTable.where(x=> x.StudentId == QueryStudentId && x.ExceptionlalRecord ==QueryExceptionalRecord ).Count() > 0)
    retrun db.StudentTable.where(x=> x.StudentId == QueryStudentId && x.ExceptionlalRecord == QueryExceptionalRecord);
else 
    return db.StudentTable.where(x=> x.StudentId == QueryStudentId && x.ExceptionlalRecord == null);
```

The else part is not returning any data, I am using an Oracle database as a data source and Entity Framework on my solution. Can any one point me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using entity framework? This is completely dependent on which linq driver you're using and which db you're using. You need to clarify what those are.

Comment: Yes i mentioned i am using oracle DBMS I will add EF too, thanks.

Comment: If you are trying to fudge tables into EF without having primary keys defined, then you're going to have problems. You really should fix the database first.

Comment: Yes, but i don't have access to do that nor that is possible because i am not the only one referring to it.

Comment: Then EF may not be a good fit for your purpose. Perhaps try Dapper?

Comment: I'll try that thanks.

Comment: Check what is your UseDatabaseNullSemantics  settings of your EF
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.usedatabasenullsemantics(v=vs.113).aspx